# How do i fix this to make the win condition work, as well as add a lose condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, text-based

So i have a project due for a text-based adventure game in python with multiple rooms, items to collect, and win/lose conditions. I got most of it to work, but I cannot get the win condition to trigger nor can i figure out how to set the lose condition.

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

class Room:
    def __init__(self, description, exits, items):
        self.description = description
        self.exits = exits
        self.items = items



rooms = {
    'town_road': Room("You are on the town road. There is a square to the north, a house to the east, and a side street to the west.", {'north': 'square', 'east': 'house_1', 'west': 'side_street'}, []),
    'house_1': Room("You are in a house with a villager. The Fire Stone is on an alter. The Town Road is behind you to the west.", {'west': 'town_road'}, [Item('fire stone', 'A stone of pure Fire Magic')]),
    'side_street': Room('You walk onto the side street. To the east runs the Town Road, north of you is a house, a shop to the south and the west street to the west.', {'east': 'town_road', 'north': 'house_2', 'south': 'shop', 'west': 'west_street'}, [Item('wind stone', 'A stone of pure Wind Magic')]),
    'house_2': Room("You enter a house with a villager. The Ice Stone is on the table. The Side Street is out the door to the south.", {'south': 'side_street'}, [Item('ice stone', 'A stone of pure Ice Magic')]),
    'shop': Room("You enter the shop and meet the shopkeeper. He holds the Wind Stone. The side street is behind you to the north.", {'north': 'side_street'}, [Item('wind stone', 'A stone of pure Wind Magic')]),
    'west_street': Room("You walk onto the next street over. There is the side street to the east, an additional road to your north, a blacksmiths shop to your south and a house to the west.", {'east': 'side_street', 'south': 'blacksmiths', 'west': 'house_3', 'north': "north_street"}, []),
    'house_3': Room('You enter a house with a villager. The Water Stone is on a counter. The West Street is behind you to the east.', {'east': 'west_street'}, [Item('water stone', 'A stone of pure Water Magic')]),
    'blacksmiths': Room('You enter a blacksmiths forge, where the blacksmith is holding out the Earth Stone. The west street is behind you to the north.', {'north': 'west_street'}, [Item('earth stone', 'A Stone of pure Earth Magic')]),
    'north_street': Room('You walk onto the north street, where there is a single house to the west and the square to the east.', {'west': 'house_4', 'east': 'square'}, []),
    'house_4': Room('You enter another house, where a child waits with the Lightning Stone. The north street is behind you to the east.', {'east': 'north_street'}, [Item('lightning stone', 'A stone of pure Lightning Magic')]),
    'square': Room("You enter the square with the demon. Have you collected all the elemental stones?", {'south': 'town_road'}, [Item('key', 'A small key')]),
}

current_room = rooms['town_road']
inventory = []


required_items = ['fire stone', 'ice stone', 'water stone', 'earth stone', 'wind_stone', 'lightning_stone']
def win_condition(inventory, required_items):
    for items in required_items:
        if items not in inventory:
            return False
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print(current_room.description)
        print(inventory)
        print(required_items)

        if win_condition(inventory, required_items):
            print('Congratulations! You have collected all the stones and won the game!')
            break

        command = input('> ').lower().strip()

        if command == 'quit':
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            break

        elif command == 'go north':
            if 'north' in current_room.exits:
                current_room = rooms[current_room.exits['north']]
            else:
                print("You can't go that way.")

        elif command == 'go south':
            if 'south' in current_room.exits:
                current_room = rooms[current_room.exits['south']]
            else:
                print("You can't go that way.")

        elif command == 'go east':
            if 'east' in current_room.exits:
                current_room = rooms[current_room.exits['east']]
            else:
                print("You can't go that way")



        elif command == 'go west':
            if 'west' in current_room.exits:
                current_room = rooms[current_room.exits['west']]
            else:
                print("You can't go that way")


        elif command.startswith('pick up'):
            item_name = command[8:].strip()
            for item in current_room.items:
                if item.name == item_name:
                    inventory.append(item)
                    current_room.items.remove(item)
                    print(f"You picked up the {item.name}.")
                    break
            else:
                print("There is nothing here by that name.")




        elif command == 'inventory':
            print("You are carrying:")
            for item in inventory:
                print(f"- {item.name}")


        else:
            print('Invalid command. Try going north, south, east, or west, picking up an item, or checking your inventory.')
```

I have tried numerous ways to get the win condition to work. However, it doesn't register I had all the items required, and I don't know how to tie it to a specific room. Any help and explanation as to what i did wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Spelling counts.  Your item names seem to have an underscore sometimes and a space other times.  Look very carefully. I think that will fix your problem.  Advice: good Python style is to limit line lengths to 80 characters.  That would make your code more readable.

Comment: I went in and fixed that bit, the underscore was an accident. It still doesn't seem to trigger the win condition though, when i go through and collect all the stones. Plus, the inventory display does something weird as well. 
[<__main__.Item object at 0x00000263E77B80D0>, <__main__.Item object at 0x00000263E77B0C40>]

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: if class doesn't have special function `__repr__` (and/or `__str__`) then `print()` doesn't know what to display when you try to print list with items - and it display `<__main__.Item object at 0x00000263E77B80D0>` with `class name` and its address in memory. If you add `def __repr__(self): return self.name` then it will display name of item.

Comment: you didn't explain when player `win`, when player `lose`? Describe it in question - not in comments

Comment: maybe in `win_condition` you should use `print( inventory, item, items not in inventory )` to see what code is doing. And you will see if you don't have another mistake/typo in items.

Comment: I don't know what you means `tie it to a specific room` but it may need to keep items as pairs `(item_name, room_name)` in inventory or in `required_items`. or it may need to use dictionary `required_items = {room_name: items, ...}` to check only some of items in current room.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your `Room` and `Item` classes to [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), you'd be able to see what's going wrong here.

```
<__main__.Item object at 0x00000263E77B80D0>
```

This is the object representation of your item class. This is because you do

```
if item.name == item_name:
    inventory.append(item)
```

So the type of `inventory` is `list[Item]`. But the type of `required_items` is `list[str]`.

So when you iterate through `required_items`, you are getting strings. But then you're checking if they are in the inventory, but of course they aren't because only `Item` objects are in the inventory.

So you need to change you win condition to something like

```
def win_condition(inventory, required_items):
    item_names = [i.name for i in inventory]
    for items in required_items:
        if items not in item_names:
            return False
    return True
```

---

Plus as other people have mentioned, you need your item names to actually match what you have in the `required_items`.

Some other tips:

1. Use dataclasses, then you would be able to see what's going wrong.
2. Keep all the lines a maximum of 100 characters - you can use [black](https://github.com/psf/black) to help you here.
3. Add typing. This would clear up a lot of issues. i.e. `def win_condition(inventory: list[Item], required_items: list[str]) -> bool` - even just running a typechecker would have caught that error.
4. Use enums for the item names, then you can't have mismatches.